# mcrypt PHP in .Net

Tags: php, .net, mcrypt

After some research on the net I didn't find any info to help me to "translate" this PHP code in .NET.
If someone has an idea ;)

```
function cryptDatas($text, $datas) {
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND);
    return base64_encode($iv . mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, pack('H*', $text), json_encode($datas), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
}
```

$text is a string,
$datas is an array like this

```
$datas = [
    'param1' => 'val1',
    'param2' => 'val2',
    'param3' => 'val3'
];
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it has been abandonware for nearly a decade now. It has therefore been deprecated and will be removed from the core and into PECL in PHP 7.2. It does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution, are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: Blowfish should not be used in new code, even  it's creator now uses AES.